# Filter questions by poster and tag

Tags: support, search

Is there a way to filter a question by the person asking it one (or more) of the assigned tags?  For example, find the questions posted by me tagged with `crystal-reports`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Search for

```
[crystal-reports] user:{user-id}
```

For specifically yourself, you can use

```
[crystal-reports] user:me
```

There's lots more options available in the [Help Center](/help/searching).